# how can i fix this error in a bison code?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, bison

i have a problem with compiling a bison code, trying to compile this code:

```
 %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdstring.h>
    //#include "list.h"
    int yylex();
    int errore = 0;
    void yyerror(char const *s);
%}
%union{
    char *stringa;
    double reale;
    int intero;
}
%start Input
%token <stringa> MATR
%token <reale> CFU COD_M
%token <intero> ANNO_C VOTO
%token AA DATA MATERIA SEP1 SEP2 VIR LANC PEV PAR_I PAR_F TRAT NOME
%define parse.error verbose
%%
Input : AA DATA SEP1 Corsi SEP2 Studenti
    ;
Corsi : El_Materie
    ;
El_Materie : Materie 
        El_Materie Materie
    ;
Materie : PAR_I COD_M VIR MATERIA VIR ANNO_C VIR CFU PAR_F 
    ;
Studenti : El_Studenti
    ;
El_Studenti : Studente Lista_M
    El_Studenti Studente Lista_M
    ;
Studente : MATR LANC NOME PEV ANNO_C PEV
    ;
Lista_M : Esame
    Lista_M Esame
    ;
Esame : COD_M VIR VOTO TRAT
    ;
%%
void yyerror(char const *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "Errore: %s\n", s);
}

int main(void){
    if(yyparse() == 0){
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me back this error:

```
Carriera1.y: warning: 10 nonterminals useless in grammar [-Wother]
Carriera1.y: warning: 10 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
Carriera1.y:16.8-13: fatal error: no phrase is derived from the initial symbol Start
   16 | %start Input
```

how can i fix this error?
same error in windows CMD and in Linux Bash.
I try with other initial symbol but the error is the same.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

i have a new error
compilng with "-Wall -Werror"

the error is:

```
Carriera.fl: In function ‘yylex’:
Carriera.fl:38:17: error: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   38 | {Matr}      {yylval.stringa = strdup(yytext); return(MATR);}
      |                 ^
At top level:
lex.yy.c:1251:16: error: ‘input’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
 1251 |     static int input  (void)
      |                ^~~~~
lex.yy.c:1208:17: error: ‘yyunput’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
 1208 |     static void yyunput (int c, char * yy_bp )
      |                 ^~~~~~~
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a rule with multiple alternatives, separate the alternatives using the `|` operator, not line breaks. You can certainly keep the line breaks for readability, but the `|` operator is what actually separates the alternatives.

```
Lista_M : Esame 
    Lista_M Esame
```

This is the same as `Lista_M : Esame Lista_M Esame` and thus infinitely recursive, which is why the rule can't match anything.

The same applies to the other rules where you're trying to use multiple alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem persists

Comment: @KevinAmico When I copy-and-paste your code and add a `|` wherever you have rules that are supposed to have multiple alternatives, the errors disappear.